# I want to spin the icons correctly on click on corresponding icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

in this html code I have tried to rotate an icon 180 degree on click on that corresponding icon and return when click on other icon or outside. **The problem here is that** the first icon does not return when click on the second and the second is does not return either click on first icon or click on outside. How to fix it?

```js
function rotate(e){
  document.getElementById("me").className="spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

function resetRotation(){
  document.getElementById("me").className="spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
}

document.addEventListener('click', resetRotation);
function rotatea(e){
  document.getElementById("you").className="spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.spinner.in{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner.out{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i onclick="rotate(event)" id="me" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down "></i>
<i onclick="rotatea(event)" id="you" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```

Comment: i don't know who are the down voting jerks without made any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function rotate(e){
  resetRotation();
  document.getElementById("me").className="spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

function resetRotation(){
  document.getElementById("me").className="spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
  document.getElementById("you").className="spinner out fa fa-caret-down";
}

function rotatea(e){
  resetRotation();
  document.getElementById("you").className="spinner in fa fa-caret-down";
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.addEventListener('click', resetRotation);
```

```css
.spinner {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.spinner.in{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner.out{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i onclick="rotate(event)" id="me" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down "></i>
<i onclick="rotatea(event)" id="you" class="spinner fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```